# singleton and thread do not work together

Tags: java

I have a singleton class which is also Runnable (and Observable). When I'm trying to start the thread from main, it does not create a new thread and gets stuck in the main loop.

```
public class A extends Observable implements Runnable
{
    private static A instance = null;

    private A() {     
    }

    public static A getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
           instance = new A();
        }
        return instance;
     }


    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        while (true) {

            System.out.print("\nSleeping");
            // sleep        
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.print("\n[Error]");
            }                      
        }
    }

}
```

and the main class:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(A.getInstance());
thread.run();
System.out.print("\nAfter...");
```

I cant see the "After" log, just the "Sleeping" in a loop. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling run(), instead of start().

Comment: And...  (it would be nice of you to explain the difference.)

Comment: The difference is, `start()` is the method that the library provides for you to call when you want to start a new thread.  `run()` is the method that _you_ provide for the library to call _in_ the new thread.